# Are there other advanced topics similar with markov process?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

I want to make current day depends on a random days rather than yesterday
or depends on specified past days for example two days, then change bayes equations

but my talent is not enough to deal with these, i am glad if there is some examples for me to follow, or direct me to another advanced topics besides markov

if i am know that today depends on some days such as 3 days before, 5 days before
how bayes would be?

Comment: every process with a finite memory is a Markov process over an extended state space

Comment: does you mean depends on yesterday or depends on 3 days before yesterday are the same? i do not know about extended state space, why only depends on yesterday, how about random a day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processes such that the state at time $t+1$ depends on the states between times $t-D_t$ and $t$, where $D_t$ is random, are called variable length Markov chains (VLMC).

The canonical reference on this is a paper by Bühlmann and Wyner, available [here](http://stat-reports.lib.berkeley.edu/accessPages/479.html) and published in *The Annals of Statistics* in 1999. A link with probabilistic dynamical source models is established in 2002 in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.2986) by Cénac et al.

Comment: what is the name of paper 2002, can not see now

Comment: @Scott Changed the link, sorry about the inconvenience.